# Laravel auth middleware seems to not work after logout on particular route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I've implemented in my web app a part where user can't make a download of a resource (`rapport`) if he/she is not authenticated. The route in the `web.php` file looks like this:

```
//DOWNLOAD RAPPORT
Route::get('telecharger/{id}', 'downloadRapport@download')->middleware('auth');
```

And in the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Rapport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class downloadRapport extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function download($id){
        $rapport = Rapport::findOrFail($id);
        return response()->download(storage_path('app/'.$rapport->path) , $rapport->fichierRapport);
    }
}
```

I thought it works perfect until I found out something lately. 
In order to download a `rapport`, a user must be authenticated as the logic suggests it. This means that once he is not anymore logged in, he has to re-enter his credentials to download the `rapport`. 
BUT, what I've found out is that when the user once entered his credentials to download a `rapport` of a particular id, even if he logs out, he can download that particular rapport. For the other rapports, he has to log in first. And so on. May it have something with sessions (just a supposition..)? But why on this route in particular when auth middleware works fine on the others? Any of your help is welcome

Comment: sounds more like browser caching / proxy or something ... side note: you are defining the `auth` middleware for all methods in that controller, and you are assigning it on the route definition as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer @lagbox. This explains better my issue indeed. Well, isn't it a problem somehow? Like some privacy problems: resources I want to be available only when logged in. It may sound as a noob question.. but why the logout which may kill the session doesn't 'remove' all data supposed available within?.. Even if there's the browser caching...

Comment: and for your side note, yes. Is that a problem or bad doing so?

Comment: if it is some caching type thing then the request isn't even making it to the site  ... change that method to return nothing and see if you still end up with a file

Comment: @lagbox, oh I see, I just tried it and it still launching the download

Comment: then I guess it really has nothing with the logic but much more the browser caching as you've said